# update sql getting select more than one row

Tags: sql, db2-400

Following query is throwing the error `[SQL0811]`

It says that the result of the SELECT returns more than one row.  But when I run the queries individually, they return one row per key.

Think I need to have another WHERE clause checking table 2 and table 1.  But how do I get visibility to table 2 outside of the SELECT and into the WHERE clause?

I tried something like this before the EXISTS:

```
where a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2 and a.key3  b.key3,
```

But when I run that I get the error:

> column or global variable 'key1' not defined

```
UPDATE table 1 AS a
SET (a.col1, a.col2, a.col3) = (
    SELECT coalesce(b.col1, 'N'), coalesce(b.col2, 'N'), coalesce(b.col3, 'N')
    FROM table 2 b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table 1 c
    ON b.key1 = c.key1
      AND b.key2 = c.key2
      AND b.key3 = c.key3
)
WHERE (a.col1 = ' ' OR a.col2 = ' ' OR a.col3 = ' ')
  AND EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM table c trk
                 INNER JOIN table d sts ON trk.key1 = sts.key1
        WHERE trk.key1 = a.key1
          AND sts.status IN (' ', 'REQ')
    )
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want a *correlated subquery* for the `set` query:

```
UPDATE table1 a
    SET (a.col1, a.col2, a.col3) = (
        SELECT coalesce(b.col1, 'N'), coalesce(b.col2, 'N'), coalesce(b.col3, 'N')
        FROM table2 b
        WHERE b.key1 = a.key1 AND
              b.key2 = a.key2 AND
              b.key3 = a.key3
       )
    WHERE . . .;
```

EDIT:

If you want to ensure that the subquery in the `SET` returns exactly one row and the columns are never `NULL`, then use aggregation:

```
UPDATE table1 a
    SET (a.col1, a.col2, a.col3) = (
        SELECT coalesce(MAX(b.col1), 'N'), coalesce(MAX(b.col2), 'N'), coalesce(MAX(b.col3), 'N')
        FROM table2 b
        WHERE b.key1 = a.key1 AND
              b.key2 = a.key2 AND
              b.key3 = a.key3
       )
    WHERE . . .;
```

Comment: previously tried what you suggested and get Null values not allowed in col1 [SQL0407] error, I need the Left join to account for nulls and have coalesce handle

Answer (score 0):

Gordon has the answer for why you are getting the `SQL0811`, and how to fix it. Let's break down the update statement:

```
UPDATE table 1 AS a
SET (a.col1, a.col2, a.col3) = (
    SELECT coalesce(b.col1, 'N'), coalesce(b.col2, 'N'), coalesce(b.col3, 'N')
    FROM table 2 b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table 1 c
    ON b.key1 = c.key1
      AND b.key2 = c.key2
      AND b.key3 = c.key3
)
WHERE ...
```

Here it looks like you are trying to update `table 1` from a sub-query. But, that subquery has no connection to `a`. So it is returning all the rows in `table 2` plus the matching rows from `table 1` with nulls where there is no match. Since `table 2` has multiple rows in it, you are getting `SQL0811`. You need to use a correlated sub-query as Gordon suggested to avoid returning all the rows in `table 2` for each row to be updated.

```
UPDATE table 1 AS a
SET (a.col1, a.col2, a.col3) = (
    SELECT coalesce(b.col1, 'N'), coalesce(b.col2, 'N'), coalesce(b.col3, 'N')
    FROM table 2 b
    WHERE b.key1 = a.key1
      AND b.key2 = a.key2
      AND b.key3 = a.key3
)
WHERE ...
```

But, it also appears that there is not a row in `table 2` for each row in `table 1` which is why you get the `SQL0407`. In order to prevent that, you need to only update rows in `table 1` that have a row in `table 2`. This is handled by adding the following to the outer WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE table 1 a
   ...
WHERE (key1, key2, key3) in (SELECT key1, key2, key3 FROM table 2)
```

Now, it occurs to me, though you didn't specify this outright, that you might want to set `(col1, col2, col3)` to `('N', 'N', 'N')` where there is not a `table 2` row that matches the `table 1` row. As the above example only updates matching rows, it will not get the unmatching rows. You can do this with a separate UPDATE, or, to include that possibility in the same UPDATE as the first, you will need a combination of Gordon's answer with a modification of your query. You still need the correlated sub-query, and you still need a left join, but you need all the rows from `table 1` plus the matching rows from `table 2`, not the other way around. That looks like this:

```
UPDATE table 1 AS a
SET (a.col1, a.col2, a.col3) = (
    SELECT coalesce(c.col1, 'N'), coalesce(c.col2, 'N'), coalesce(c.col3, 'N')
    FROM table 1 b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table 2 c
      ON b.key1 = c.key1
        AND b.key2 = c.key2
        AND b.key3 = c.key3
    WHERE a.key1 = b.key1
      and a.key2 = b.key2
      and a.key3 = b.key3
)
WHERE ...
```

And for completeness, you wrote:

> I tried something like this before the EXISTS:
>
> `where a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2 and a.key3  b.key3,`
>
> But when I run that I get the error:
>
> > column or global variable 'key1' not defined

That is because `b` is in scope only for the sub-select, and cannot be found in the outer where clause. So `b.key1` is not defined there. As you can see, SQL error messages are not always the best.